# Angular 4 Circular dependency detected src\app\app.module.ts

Tags: angular

problem when ng build --prod

```
WARNING in Circular dependency detected: src\app\app.module.ts -> src\app\app.module.ngfactory.js -> src\app\app.module.ts
```

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgMod

```
ule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DemoMaterialModule } from './material-module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatButtonModule, MatListModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { SideNavComponent } from './side-nav/side-nav.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SideNavComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    DemoMaterialModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatListModule,
LayoutModule
```

],
  exports: [

```
MatSidenavModule,
MatToolbarModule
```

],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]`enter code here`
})
export class AppModule { }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

Comment: Please put your app.module.ts code here.